# Force Update of RelativeSource Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding, datatemplate, observablecollection, itemscontrol

for my application, I have an ItemsControl which has a distinct template (shorthanded as Template2) for the first item, and a default template (Template1) for the rest of the items. I have done so with the following XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="TemplateContentPresenter"
                      Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource Template1}"/>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
     Converter= {StaticResource IsFirstItemInCollectionConverter}}"
                     Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="TemplateContentPresenter"
                    Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource Template2}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

The IsFirstItemInCollectionConverter's code is as follows:

```
public class IsFirstItemInCollectionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DependencyObject item = (DependencyObject)value;
        ItemsControl ic = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item);
        Console.WriteLine("converted");
        return (ic.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) == 0);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my binding does not update when I make a change in the itemssource of the itemsControl. (In the view that displays the itemsControl, I have buttons which can add and remove items). The binding updates and shows the correct template only after I switch the view, and reload it. How can I correct this behavior? I'm assuming I have to set the UpdateSourceTrigger to explicit and update the source manually, but I have no idea how to do it inside a datatemplate. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have triggered your DataTrigger on `Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}` which will get triggered when the ListBoxItem's datacontext change.

I will suggest here to use DataTemplateSelector for your item control and set `ItemTemplateSelector` property to it. In SelectTemplate method you can return the template for newly added item depending on any logic:

TemplateSelector:

```
 public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate FirstItemTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate DefaultItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        //Logic to return first or default template comes here
    }
}
```

In xaml:

```
<local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplate">
        <local:MyTemplateSelector.FirstItemTemplate>
            <!--First Template-->
        </local:MyTemplateSelector.FirstItemTemplate>

        <local:MyTemplateSelector.DefaultItemTemplate>
            <!--Default Template-->
        </local:MyTemplateSelector.DefaultItemTemplate>
    </local:MyTemplateSelector>
```

**UPDATE**

For your particular case if you are not using alternation in your itemsControl you can solve this like below also. You can use AlternationCount to you ListBox and bind to ItemsControl.AlternationIndex for each ListboxItem. So whenever listbox alternation index changes you can change its template:

XAML:

```
<ListBox AlternationCount="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" x:Name="itemControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource FirstTemplate}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Here DefaultTemplate and FirstTemplate are controlTemplates.

I tried it and it worked for me whenever I remove item at index 0, it gives the next item first item template.

Hope it works for you.

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I used the method you described, but the same problem occurs; the template does not update as soon as I remove index 0 of the ObservableCollection that the ItemsControl is bound to. I need to switch views before the update applies. Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it but in an inelegant manner. I set my bound item to null temporarily to force a re-evaluation by the DataTemplateSelector every time an item is removed/added.